# Measuring performance for simple vectorized array operations

Tags: optimization, visual-c++, x86, performancecounter, avx512

I'm optimizing simple array operations such as

```
for (int i=0; i<cnt; i++) dst[i] = src1[i] * src2[i];
```

where cnt is usually 32 to 1024, which are the typical cases in my app. I'm comparing Intel IPP, MSVC 2017 native vectorizer, and I'm also exploiting intrinsics for AVX and AVX512 in MSVC. I set the thread priority to critical and thread affinity mask to "1". Then I use QueryPerformanceCounter to calculate the time in the beginning and at the end of the "operation", which consists of running the loop millions of times. Running on a new i9 with 10 cores.

The problem is the results are varying, a LOT. Sometimes the op takse 3 seconds, sometimes 4. This makes the results basically unusable. Any ideas what could be wrong? The values in the arrays being processed are always the same, the arrays are aligned to 32 byte boundaries.

Comment: Something running in the background? Like antivirus? Also try set affinity to different core. Simple code like this can have some time differences but small, not like 25%

Comment: Thanks Anty, but I don't think so, especially since this is a very fast CPU with lots of cores.

Comment: Are your arrays FP or integer?  Agner Fog's testing indicates that `vpmulld zmm` only has 1 per 2 clock throughput on SKX (i.e. it doesn't take advantage of the port-5 FMA unit to run its 2 uops according to https://agner.org/optimize/), so with unrolling, it looks like AVX512 will bottleneck at the same at the same throughput as an unrolled AVX2 loop for `int32_t`.  AVX512 is better for any other type, though.

Comment: It's all 32-bit floats now, I don't really need integral arithmetics. The problem here is that the results are far too inaccurate. I even tried __rdtsc to get CPU timestamp, but it's still different every time... Even the same algorithm gets compeltely different results...

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU or OS is probably throttling the frequency of the core.  It might be running at 3.6 GHZ one time and 2.8 GHZ another.  There are ways to prevent this with Windows and/or your BIOS but I don't remember the specifics.

Also this simple operation is going to be memory bound so the differences between compilers or AVX2 vs AVX512 will be trivial.

Comment: The thing is, the algorithms are actually using the exact same buffers, so the situation for all should be exactly the same. Yet, sometimes one is like 2x faster, another time it is the other way around... I don't think it's possible to fix the core frequency, last time I checked the turboboost was fully automatic and only OS was able to control it.

Comment: Doesn't matter if the conditions are the same.  If the CPU is running to hot, it could automatically throttle various cores.  Same with the OS, if it deems that it's background tasks on other cores is more necessary, it might be throttling the current core you are running on one time and not the next.

Comment: This won't be memory-bound.  The OP is repeating (millions of times) a tiny loop over 32 to 1024 elements (of unspecified size, but even 8-byte `double` would only be 8kiB * 3 = 24kiB, which fits in L1d cache.)  With sufficient unrolling or whatever to avoid bottlenecks on the front-end, this should run at 1 vector store per clock.  @VojtěchMeldaMeluzín: How exactly are you timing it?  Are you giving it long enough to ramp up to max turbo?  You can disable turbo and set the governor to Performance.  (IDK how on Windows, though.)  You're only measuring wall-clock time, not core clock cycles.

Comment: @VojtěchMeldaMeluzín: Is is possible that your loop is sometimes spanning a 32-byte code boundary and running at half speed because of uop-cache effects?  (Skylake-X has a disabled loop buffer, so tiny not-unrolled loops can suffer depending on code alignment.)  Does the *same* binary sometimes run at different speeds, or is the variation only between different builds?

Comment: I'm using floats, so it should definitely fit the L1 cache imho. I also tried placing everything into continous block in stack, no difference. I'm using QueryPerformanceTimer and now I tried __rdtsc getting statistics of single (or a few) iterations. I run the whole OP 4 times in a row, printing the stats like median clock cycle count and overall time, and the 4 times are always nearly identical, but next time I run the app the times are sometimes even like 30% different...

Comment: I'm not sure about the 32-byte code boundary (I actually didn't know about this problem), but my guess is that the app should be always placed at the same memory address right? So that shouldn't matter imho.

Comment: Peter is correct.  I overlooked the size of the array.  Maybe you should consider downloading an evaluation copy of Vtune Amplifier.  This is a very powerful tool to help with these types of problems.

Comment: You're problem sounds like the OS migrating the data from one core to another.  I've seen the problem before.  Can you try a test where you place the data on the same core as the code?